# Can coats button themselves? (Active vs. Passive)

Tags: grammaticality, transitivity, active-vs-passive

While doing copywork today, I came across this sentence:

> Tall and well made, the men dressed in dark silk **coats that buttoned down the sides of the chest** and were elaborately embroidered in silver or gold. Each one looked like a general on the field.

How can silk coats button themselves down? Shouldn't it have been "dark silk coats that **were** buttoned down **to the** sides of the chest?"

Is "were" elided for brevity's sake because it can be inferred from the context or is it not needed at all?

Comment: *Buttons* is intransitive here. The coats  fasten by means of buttons. *This door opens inward*

Comment: I would have taken issues with “tall and well made”.  Unless they were “made men” in the Mafia sense.

Comment: ... or perhaps the Uruk-hai sense.

Comment: @DjinTonic Thank you!

Comment: *This coat **buttons** down [at] the front* (as opposed to passive ***...is buttoned down...***) is the same kind of "inverted" verb usage as, say, *This wine **is drinking** well,* where the subject uses a verb "actively" instead of passively. It won't work in all contexts, and not all native speakers will agree on exactly when it does or doesn't work, but I personally have no problem with the cited usage.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, FumbleFingers says:

> *This coat **buttons** down [at] the front* (as opposed to passive ...***is buttoned down***...) is the same kind of "inverted" verb usage as, say, *This wine **is drinking** well*, where the subject uses a verb "actively" instead of passively. It won't work in all contexts, and not all native speakers will agree on exactly when it does or doesn't work, but I personally have no problem with the cited usage.

I agree with this. "The way a piece of clothing is fastened" can be described in the active voice, even when this might not make logical sense:

> A coat that buttoned down the sides
> A dress which zips up the back
> Shoes that Velcro shut

This usage of the active voice is especially common when describing the *location* (and *direction*) of the fastening mechanism ("down the sides," "up the back").

---

"Tall and well made," however, is *not* correct.

First of all, "well-made" is a compound adjective and must be hyphenated. But more importantly, "Tall and well-made" describes "the men"—and this does not make sense.

We do not describe humans as being "made" (except in a specific non-gradable context meaning ["a member of the Mafia"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Made_man)). In the context of religion it is common to talk about some "Creator" which *created* humanity, and perhaps even individual humans, but we use the word "created" and not "made." "Made" is reserved only for deliberately constructed things.

Somewhat confusingly, we do use the adjectives "[built](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/built#Adjective)"<sup>1</sup> and "[well-built](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/well-built#Adjective)"<sup>2</sup> to describe a person.

So if the sentence means that **the men** were both tall and athletic-looking:

> Tall and well-built, the men dressed in dark silk coats...

But if instead **the coats** are tall (long) and well-constructed:

> The men dressed in tall well-made dark silk coats...

Or if the men are tall and the coats are well-constructed:

> The tall men dressed in well-made dark silk coats...

Note that if there is only one adjective describing the men, it must come after the article. "Tall, the men dressed in..." would be incorrect.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Wiktionary: (*informal*) well-built, muscular or toned.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup>Wiktionary: Muscular and lean, having a body resembling that of an athlete.</sup>

Comment: I didn't notice it before, but you're quite right to flag up that erroneous initial ["dangling modifier"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier) in OP's text. Syntactically, it's ***the men*** who are being described as both ***tall*** AND ***well-made***, which makes no sense at all. I'm sure linguists / grammarians have a word for when verbs like ***to button, to drink, to zip*** are used in this way (where what would normally be the ***object*** in a transitive use of the verb is switched to a "self-referential" ***intransitive*** usage with that object as the ***subject***).

Comment: (I'm still hoping *someone* here will know the technical term for such "inverted" verb usages... :)